# Index Manipulation of Summation in Real Cosine Transform Fast Computation

Tags: summation, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Consider $X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{2N}$ for $k=0,1,2,...,N-1$. Now we define $g_{n} = x_{n} + x_{N-1-n}$ and $h_{n} = \frac{x_{n}-x_{N-1-n}}{2\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{2N}}$ for $\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{N-1}$ and $\{g_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}$, $\{h_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}$. Next, we also define $G_{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}g_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}$ and $H_{k}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}h_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}$. Note that $X_{k}$ is in the context of being the real cosine transform of $x_{n}$.
Show that $G_{k}=X_{2k}$ and $H_{k}+H_{k+1}=X_{2k+1}$!

So, here is my attempt so far:
Observe that
$$X_{2k}= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}$$
$$X_{2k}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}+ \sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}$$
$$X_{2k}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}+ \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{i+\frac{N}{2}}\cos\big(\frac{(2i+1)k\pi}{N} + \frac{k\pi}{2}\big) $$
and I do not know what to do from here on since the form does not match.
Then, I also have tried the second part but I find myself to not be able to do further as well.
Observe that
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}h_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N} + \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}h_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)(k+1)\pi}{N} $$
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}h_{n}\bigg[\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N} + \cos\frac{(2n+1)(k+1)\pi}{N}\bigg]$$
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}h_{n}2\cos\frac{(2n+1)(2k+1)\pi}{2N}\cos\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2N}$$
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}\frac{x_{n}-x_{N-1-n}}{2\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{2N}}2\cos\frac{(2n+1)(2k+1)\pi}{2N}\cos\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2N}$$
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}(x_{n}-x_{N-1-n})\cos\frac{(2n+1)(2k+1)\pi}{2N}$$
$$H_{k}+H_{k+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)(2k+1)\pi}{2N}-\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{N-1-n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)(2k+1)\pi}{2N}$$
Again, I do not know what I have to do at this point since I cannot manipulate the index of the summation to get the result I want.
Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think the factor $k$ in $h_n$ should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first part. We want to show equality $G_k=X_{2k}$ with
\begin{align*}
G_k&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}\left(x_n+x_{N-1+n}\right)\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}\\
X_{2k}&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{G_k}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}\left(x_n+x_{N-1+n}\right)\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}}\\
> &=\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_n\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}}_{=: A}+\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{N-1+n}\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}\\
> &=A+\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{N-1+\left(\frac{N}{2}-1-n\right)}\cos\frac{\left(2\left(\frac{N}{2}-1-n\right)+1\right)k\pi}{N}\tag{1}\\
> &=A+\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_{\frac{N}{2}+n}\cos\frac{\left(N-1-2n\right)k\pi}{N}\\
> &=A+\sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N-1}x_{\frac{N}{2}-\left(n+\frac{N}{2}\right)}\frac{\cos\left(N-1-2\left(n-\frac{N}{2}\right)\right)k\pi}{N}\tag{2}\\
> &=A+\sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N-1}x_n\frac{\cos\left(2N-1-2n\right)k\pi}{N}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1}x_n\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}+\sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N-1}x_n\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\cos\frac{(2n+1)k\pi}{N}=X_{2k}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of summation of the right-hand sum: $n\rightarrow \frac{N}{2}-1-n$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $n=\frac{N}{2}$.
- In (3) we use that $\cos$ is an even function and periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not think to change order of summation! You help me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: One more bit question though on (1) in $H_k + H_{k+1}$, why can we change $-$ sign into $+$?

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra: Sorry, this was a typo of mine and at the time I don't see how to correct it. I'll check it after work. You could also check this part for small $N$ and see if the problem is stated correctly.